# Problem with the IntelliJ version in the plug-in

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, intellij-plugin

When I set an IntelliJ version as described below I have the following error

```
intellij {
    version '2022.3'
}
```

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'brs-plugin'.
>
> > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > Failed to query the value of extension 'intellij' property 'version'.
> > > The value for the 'intellij.version' property was not specified, see:
> > https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html#intellij-extension-version

But if I add the equal operator have the following

```
intellij {
    version = '2022.3'
}
```

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException:
> Could not resolve com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIC:2022.3.

This is my full version of the build.gradle. As you can see I have added several repos, but it's not helped. Full version of the project you can found on this [link](https://github.com/vladimirkozhaev/brainstorm-vkozhaev-intellij-plugin/tree/apply_stackowerflow)
How to fix my problem? Regards

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }

        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }

        maven {
            url "https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/snapshots"
        }

        maven {
            url "https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/intellij-dependencies"
        }

    }


}


plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.intellij" version "1.11.0"
    id "org.jetbrains.grammarkit" version "2020.1"


}

configurations {
    configurations.compileOnly.setCanBeResolved(true)
}

group 'com.interfaced'
version = '0.2.7'


apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'

sourceSets {
    all {
        java.srcDirs += ['src/main/gen']
        kotlin.srcDirs += ['src/main/kotlin']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
    }
}

intellij {
    version = '2022.3'
}

grammarKit {
    jflexRelease = '1.7.0-2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/intellij-dependencies"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib', version: '1.7.22'

    implementation files('jars/grammar-kit.jar')
    implementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-gradle-plugin', version: '1.6.0'


}


import org.jetbrains.grammarkit.tasks.GenerateLexer
import org.jetbrains.grammarkit.tasks.GenerateParser

def GENERATE_GROUP = 'Generate'

task setConfiguration() {
    configurations.compileOnly.setCanBeResolved(true)
}
task generateLexer(type: GenerateLexer) {
    source = "src/main/grammar/BrightScript.flex"
    targetDir = "src/main/gen/com/interfaced/brs/lang/lexer"
    targetClass = "_BrsLexer"
    skeleton = "src/main/grammar/idea-flex.skeleton"
    purgeOldFiles = true

    description = 'Generate Lexer Java sources for BrightScript'
    group = GENERATE_GROUP
}

task generateParser(type: GenerateParser) {
    source = "src/main/grammar/BrightScript.bnf"
    targetRoot = 'src/main/gen'
    pathToParser = 'src/main/gen/com/interfaced/brs/lang/BrsParser.java'
    pathToPsiRoot = 'src/main/gen/com/interfaced/brs/lang/psi'
    purgeOldFiles = true

    description = 'Generate Parser Java sources for BrightScript'
    group = GENERATE_GROUP

    // patch up to date check
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
}

compileKotlin.dependsOn(setConfiguration, generateLexer, generateParser)
```